# Skip iteration of function in map

Tags: python, function, exception

I have a function `matching` that I apply to many files by `map(lambda f: matching(f),files)`.

There is one line in the function that if it raises an error, I want it to skip that file and move on to the next. Something like:

```
try: 
    doc = nlp(text)
except:
    continue
```

except if understand `continue` is only for loops. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is `try` block within a loop? if it is inside loop, you can do this. Otherwise you cannot.

Comment: No, it is not inside a loop.

Comment: you can't use continue without loop.

Comment: I'm not trying to use continue. I'm saying something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
try: 
    doc = nlp(text)
except:
    pass
```

You can only use `continue` inside a loop. You can use `pass`

Comment: Wouldn't this then continue with the rest of the function for that file though?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your code? It is unclear what your code is doing

Comment: Sorry. The try-except block is only part of the function. There is stuff done on `doc` after that. But in the "except" block, I want to move on to the next file.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try something like this:

```py
def myfunc(text):
    try:
        return True, nlp(text)
    except Exception:
        return False, None

output = (doc for success, doc in map(myfunc, files) if success)
```

Note that you typically want to except `Exception`, and not use a bare `except` to avoid catching `BaseException`s like a SIGINT (keyboard interrupt).